# HTML script tag and javascript file communication

Tags: javascript

I have a script tag in my HTML file

```
<head>
<script src="myjs.js"></script>
<script> 
</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
```

and a external javascript file  , Is there a way the variables in the script tag interact with the script in the javascript file ?

Answer (score 2):

Both the content of the script file and the following script element will be treated as global code as if they were in a single script element.

**However**, code in the first file will be executed before the content of the second script element is parsed or executed (which means that variables declared and initialised in the second script don't exist for the first script).

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Once your external file is loaded into the page, it's treated as if it was coded in the page like your second script. Depending on how you've scoped your variables, there may be conflicts and values can be changed/overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Your html structure seem invalid

should be

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myjs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

       //Now you can use external variable here

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Without DOCTYPE is still and will be very invalid.

Comment: the HTML, head and body tags can all be omitted, the only thing missing is a title element and any block element (a div or table will do). But the question isn't really about valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference variables from the javascript file from code in the script tag, you need to make sure that the javascript file has been loaded. The common way to do that is to attach a handler to the window.onload event and reference the variables from the file in that handler.  The simplest (but not necessarily the best) way to do this is as follows:

```
<script> 
  window.onload = function() {
      // reference loaded variables, domNodes, etc
  }
</script>
```

Most javascript libraries/frameworks have mechanisms for doing this. See [jQuery .ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for an example of one.

If you have a large application that you would like to split into meaningful modules, I'd recommend investigating **AMD** (Asychronous Module Definition). There is a nice set of slides describing what AMD is and why you would want to use it at http://blog.amt.in/asynchronous-module-definition-amd-why-what-a